# How do I randomise a list using random.randint() only? (CLOSED)

Tags: python

I am currently trying to get a list of questions and answers (QandA) and randomise the questions on every iteration. I know I can use choice() but I have only been taught random.randint() in terms of randomising. Can someone please help me on this? At this current state, a question and answer is asked but is not randomised. Tuples and other more advanced methods cannot be used because in my course I can only use what I am taught.

I have tried using random.randint(0, len(QandA) - 1) thinking this would randomise the list but it does not achieve the desired result.

```
import random
print("Welcome to Te Reo Maori Quiz!!!")
print("\nAnswer the questions with single Maori words")
QandA = ['A challenge laid down in chant and dance:','haka',
             'What is "Sun" in Maori:', 'ra',
             'Something you eat to fill your belly:', 'kai',
             'Type in the Maori word for "cave":', 'ana',
             'Traditional Maori food cooked in an earth oven:','hangi',
             'Ma is white, whero is red, kakariki is green, pango is black. What else is black?:', 'mangu',
             'its getting ... in here, so take off all your clothes:', 'wera',
             'What does Kia ora mean?:', 'hello',
             'What does ka pai mean?:', 'good',
             'What does kei te peha koe mean?:', 'how are you',
             'What is the Maori phrase for "what is your name?:', 'ko wai to ingoa',
             'What does hikoi mean?:', 'walk',
             'What is a waiata:', 'song',
             'What is the the Maori word for stomach?:', 'puku',
             'What does mahi mean?', 'work',
             'What is the maori word for wait?:', 'taihoa',
             'if something was nui, then it would be what?:', 'big',
             'What does Haere mai mean? (hint: it starts with "w"):', 'welcome',
             'What does nau mai mean?:', 'welcome',
             'What does tangi mean?:', 'funeral',
             ]

points = 0
current = 0
quiz = 0

while(quiz < 5):

    current = random.randint(0, len(QandA) - 1)

    question = input("Q" + str(quiz + 1) + ". " + QandA[current])
    newquestion = question.upper()
    if question == QandA[current + 1]:
        points = points + 10
        current = current + 2
        print("\nCorrect Answer!")

    elif question == newquestion:
        print("\nInvalid! Please enter only lowercase characters!")
        current = current + 2

    else:
        print("\nIncorrect answer. The correct answer is:", QandA[current+1])
        points = points - 10
        current = current + 2
    quiz = quiz + 1

    if points < 0:
        points = 0

print("End of Quiz.")
print("Your score: %", points, sep = "")
```

the expected result is to have the list randomise at every iteration and have the correct answer to that randomised question.

Comment: hint, think indexes.

Comment: From the first look, simple randomizing of `QandA` will change how questions are adjacent to their answers. It is an expected behavior?

Comment: right, I am trying to randomise the questions only. would using a seperate list help with this?

Comment: How about making tuples: `[(Q1, A1), ..., (Qn, An)]`, and randomize the list of tuples, so that you will always have respective answer for question?

Comment: I cannot use tuples as I am not taught that. for my course I can only use what is taught. and at this point my knowledge is very basic

Comment: If you want a question: `randint(0, len(QandA)//2)*2` if you want an answer `randint(0, len(QandA)//2)*2 +1`. Obviously this assumes that every question has an answer that follows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem using `random.randint(0, len(QandA) - 1)` to obtain a random index. The problem that you are having comes from your data sctructure. Having questions and answers as different elements will make it more difficult to guarantee that your index is a question.

Maybe you can change your array to array of tuples:

```
QandA = [('A challenge laid down in chant and dance:','haka'),
             ('What is "Sun" in Maori:', 'ra'),
             ('Something you eat to fill your belly:', 'kai'),
             ('Type in the Maori word for "cave":', 'ana'),
             ('Traditional Maori food cooked in an earth oven:','hangi'),
             ('Ma is white, whero is red, kakariki is green, pango is black. What else is black?:', 'mangu'),
             ('its getting ... in here, so take off all your clothes:', 'wera'),
             ('What does Kia ora mean?:', 'hello'),
             ('What does ka pai mean?:', 'good'),
             ('What does kei te peha koe mean?:', 'how are you'),
             ('What is the Maori phrase for "what is your name?:', 'ko wai to ingoa'),
             ('What does hikoi mean?:', 'walk'),
             ('What is a waiata:', 'song'),
             ('What is the the Maori word for stomach?:', 'puku'),
             ('What does mahi mean?', 'work)',
             ('What is the maori word for wait?:', 'taihoa'),
             ('if something was nui, then it would be what?:', 'big'),
             ('What does Haere mai mean? (hint: it starts with "w"):', 'welcome'),
             ('What does nau mai mean?:', 'welcome'),
             ('What does tangi mean?:', 'funeral'),
             ]
```

now you can do:

```
current = random.randint(0, len(QandA) - 1)
```

and then access it as:

```
q_a = QandA[current]
question = q_a[0]
answer = q_a[1]
```

Edit:
if you can't use tuples the other option is to use 2 separate lists and have the Q&A with the same index.

```
current = random.randint(0, len(questions) - 1)
question = questions[current]
answer = answers[current]
```

Comment: This would be the best answer if OP hasn't mentioned that `tuple` is _not_ an option. Perhaps tweak the answer a bit so that it uses (perhaps) two lists?

Comment: Yes sadly tuple isn’t an option. How would I write my random.randint code if I were to have two lists? Thanks!

Comment: That's why I edited it after posting it. Just declare 2 lists q = [Q1, Q2, Q3..Qn] and a = [A1, A2, A3...An]. Then get the random index using any of the lists (they should be the same size)

Comment: have you checked that both lists have the same number of elements?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution requiring only `random.randint()`.

A random item from the list is popped out and appended to a new list. In this way, you will not have duplicates!

Mind that the original list gets deleted in the process but if you need it in the future, you can always make a copy of it.

```
import random

x = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
rnd_x = []
while len(x):
    try:
        rnd_x.append(x.pop(random.randint(0,len(x))))
    except IndexError:
        pass

print(rnd_x)
#['F', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'E']
```